# obtener pdf desde FileOutputStream

Tags: java, pdf

estoy haciendo una aplicación donde creo unos pdf.
La he hecho de manera que me la crea en un directorio (FileOutputStream) pero me gustaría que se me abriera a través del navegador cuando haga click en el link que llama al action que lo crea.
Es en java.

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas un servlet que sea así:

```
public class PDFServlet extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet implements javax.servlet.Servlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String pdfFileName = "tu-pdf.pdf";
        String contextPath = getServletContext().getRealPath(File.separator);
        File pdfFile = new File(contextPath + pdfFileName);    
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + pdfFileName);
        response.setContentLength((int) pdfFile.length());    
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
        OutputStream responseOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        int bytes;
        while ((bytes = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
            responseOutputStream.write(bytes);
        }    
    }
}
```

También puedes hacerlo de manera similar con otros FRAMEWORKS Web para Java, pero ya que no especificaste ninguno, te pongo la manera más genérica de llevar adelante esto.

Comment: Muchas gracias, es verdad no dije el Framework. Es Struts.

Comment: En la linea del contextPath me da error el getServletContext. Pongo como creo el FileOutputStream, esto de crear ficheros se me hace un mundo, :(.                                                               FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:/BajadaPDF/Factura - "+factura.getNumeroFactura()+" - "+factura.getCliente().getRazonSocial()+".pdf");
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fos);